# Как прочитать строку из БД и выполнить как запрос?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Задача:** Есть таблица продуктов

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    productId UUID NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(16, 6) NOT NULL,
    shop VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(productId)
);
```

и таблица в которой хранятся фильтры к продуктам

```
CREATE TABLE Filters (
    sqlQuery VARCHAR(2096) NOT NULL
);
```

поле sqlQuery хранит sql запрос для выборки продуктов, который представляет собой `select * from Products where какое-то сложное условие`.

Необходимо найти все фильтры, которым соответствует хотя бы один продукт имя которого находится в заданном массиве.

**Что не получается:** попытался решить задачу одним динамическим запросом

```
select * from Filters
    where exists (
        /*Вот тут хотелось бы обратиться к полю Filters.sqlQuery и выполнить его как запрос*/
    );
```

Но собственно не знаю как сделать то, что описано в комментарии запроса выше.

**UPD**

решил использовать подход описанный в одной из ссылок в комментариях:
1.Создаем параметризованный запрос

```
select * from Filters where existProductsForFilter(?, Filters.sqlQuery)
```

2.И реализуем процедуру existProductsForFilter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION existProductsForFilter(
          productNames VARCHAR(256)[], filterQuery VARCHAR(2096))
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM EXECUTE filterQuery AS P
            WHERE P.category = ANY(productCategories)
    );
END;
$BODY$;
```

Но создать эту процедуру не получается - выскакиает ошибка
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "EXECUTE")
LINE 7:   WITH P AS EXECUTE filterQuery

Comment: Динамический запрос - это когда в хранимой процедуре (или в вызывающем Java/.Net/Python/etc коде) создаётся строковая переменная, потом с помощью конкатенации собирается SQL запрос, потом исполняется с помощью `EXECUTE`. Вот тут примеры https://stackoverflow.com/a/12780331/998126 А то что ты хочешь, это невозможно.

Comment: По той же ссылке есть и другой ответ, который может быть ближе к тому, что ты хочешь https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721603/998126